# Build failed in macOS environment

Tags: go

i want to build Mach-O in macos env ，but it faild

build command

```
CC=/usr/local/go/misc/ios/clangwrap.sh CGO_ENABLED=1  GOOS=darwin GOARCH=arm64 go build -ldflags "-w"  -o test ./main.go
```

err info

```
# command-line-arguments
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: running /usr/local/go/misc/ios/clangwrap.sh failed: exit status 1
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_darwin_arm_init_mach_exception_handler", referenced from:
      _x_cgo_init in 000005.o
  "_darwin_arm_init_thread_exception_port", referenced from:
      _threadentry in 000005.o
      _x_cgo_init in 000005.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

```
nm -gU binary | grep darwin_arm_init_mach_exception_handler
nm -gU binary | grep darwin_arm_init_thread_exception_port
```

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/nm: error: binary: No such file or directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/nm: error: binary: No such file or directory
```